# Reflection API + аннотации: как передать имя класса-наследника?

Tags: java, рефлексия, аннотации

У меня есть аннотация, в которую я хочу передать класс как параметр.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Documented
public @interface PostApiRequest {

    Class<?> value();
}
```

Аннотация вешается на метод абстрактного класса-родителя.

```
@PostApiRequest(value = ...)
@Override
public ResponseEntity<D> save(@RequestBody D dto) {
```

Приложение не знает, какой наследник вызовет метод, поэтому мне и необходимо передать параметром класс-наследник, чтобы потом работать с его аннотациями через рефлексию. Конечно, хотелось бы увидеть что-то вроде:

```
@PostApiRequest(value = this.class)    //передаём класс-наследник
@Override
public ResponseEntity<D> save(@RequestBody D dto) {
```

но такая конструкция не работает.

Подскажите, как передать класс параметром аннотации?

Comment: Если единичный наследник, то его и передавайте. А если их множество, вешайте слушатель через прокси и обрабатывайте уже там

Comment: Можно поподробнее про слушатель через прокси?

Comment: Почему не работает или в чем проблема?

Comment: Почему не работает или в чем проблема?

Comment: Проблема в том, что параметром аннотации можно передать только константу.

Answer (score 0):

[Как пример посмотрите сюда](https://github.com/GenCloud/ioc_container/blob/master/orm-factory/src/main/java/org/ioc/orm/repositories/proxy/RepositoryHandler.java), используется Cglib [функция invoke](https://github.com/GenCloud/ioc_container/blob/0bd65a11f6c6702306e474eba69a9b284523af7d/orm-factory/src/main/java/org/ioc/orm/repositories/proxy/RepositoryHandler.java#L67) обрабатывается при вызове любого метода класса CrudRepository. [Создание прокси можете глянуть тут](https://github.com/GenCloud/ioc_container/blob/0bd65a11f6c6702306e474eba69a9b284523af7d/orm-factory/src/main/java/org/ioc/orm/factory/orient/OrientSchemaFactory.java#L172)

Comment: а попроще пример есть? простите, но сплошной текст кода тяжело читать...

Comment: @Санаев, что Вам конкретно не понятно?

Comment: Правильно ли я понял, что Ваш способ - что-то вроде использования `Proxy.newProxyInstance`?

Comment: @Вячеслав Чернышов, да, но куда быстрее, чем дефолтное апи